# Integer column not incrementing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a way that will allow users to "flag" a comment for moderation.  I use an integer column on the comment that increments anytime a user hits "flag" the idea being that moderators will see the comments with the most flags first.  I got this to work with one of my models earlier and I'm going about it the same way with my comments model but it's not doing anything, not throwing any errors but also not doing anything.

**Reviews_controller.rb**

```
  def flag
      @review = Review.find(params[:id])
      @review.increment!(:flag)

  end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to 'Flag', flag_review_path(review), method: :post, :remote => true %>
```

**migration to add column for flag and useful upvote (to be implemented later)**

```
class AddColumnsToReviews < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :reviews, :flag, :integer, default: 0
    add_column :reviews, :useful, :integer, default: 0
  end
end
```

**Route for Flags **

```
  resources :reviews do
    member do
      post 'flag', :review
    end
  end
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.  Also, I don't know if this is pertinent but even though my migration states the default for these fields should be 0 in my database it's showing up as NULL.

Comment: Does your server log show a commit or rollback to the database?  Have you put breakpoints in the controller to make sure that `params[:id]` is there and that `@review` is valid?

Comment: Try specifying null: false in your migration. Do you see any SQL trace in your console when you hit ReviewsController#flag - if you don't then quite likely a routing issue.

Comment: what happens if you remove  :remote => true ?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out...  Thanks John, Henners66 and Gaston for your suggestions.  I figured out the problems by going through the server logs, it's pretty complex, and there's a good chance I'm going about this wrong (if so please feel free to give advice).

The reviews display on a "Professors" page and are pretty much tied to professors allowing students to provide a review of their professors.   The reviews controller had a `before_action :set_professor` which was preventing the flag from working.  So by adding `before_action :set_professor, :except => [:flag]` I was able to get it working.

Again thank you all for your responses and suggestions I was inspired to dig around in the server logs because of your advice.

Comment: You're welcome ... glad you got to the bottom of it and thanks for the update :). The exception in the before_action seems perfectly valid to me.